# Android Studio carregamento infinito

Tags: android-studio

Olá, desde ontem me deparo com um problema no Android Studio, Quando abre ele não termina nunca de carregar o projeto, ontem deixei por mais de 5 horas e nada... 
já apaguei a pasta `.gradle`e não adiantou, tentei abrir por um backup do meu projeto e novamente loop infinito... acabei de criar um projeto novo por enquanto esta em 15 minutos e novamente, nada !

> Reparei algo novo aqui.
>
> Exception in thread "png-cruncher_5" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\walla\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
>       at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
>       at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:121)
>       at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:205)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Exception in thread "png-cruncher_1" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\walla\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
>       at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
>       at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:121)
>       at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:205)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Exception in thread "png-cruncher_3" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\walla\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
>       at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
>       at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:121)
>       at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:205)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Exception in thread "png-cruncher_4" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\walla\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
>       at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
>       at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:121)
>       at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:205)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Exception in thread "png-cruncher_2" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\walla\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
>       at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
>       at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:121)
>       at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:205)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Você já tentou fazer o que a mensagem recomendou? Especificamente o trecho "Certifique-se que 'C:\Users\walla\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\aapt.exe' roda corretamente(alguns antivírus podem bloqueá-lo)."

Comment: terminado o café , tentarei.

Comment: botei na lista de exclusões do Avast agora foi, apesar de ter aparecido o mesmo erro no gradle console

Comment: Estou votando para fechar porque [segundo o AP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/222053/android-studio-carregamento-infinito#comment457599_222062) *"era o firewall que tava bloqueando o arquivo"*

Answer (score 0):

Conforme a mensagem (tradução livre):

> Certifique-se que
>   'C:\Users\walla\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.3‌​\aapt.exe'
>   roda corretamente(alguns antivírus podem bloqueá-lo).

Com relação a mensagem no console ela provalmente é persistente, procure por um botão 'Limpar Console' e veja se ela continua aparecendo após reiniciar o Android Studio.

Comment: compilei meu projeto algumas e 2 vezes tive que reiniciar por causa desse log, vou desativar o avast e ver como funciona, bem chato isso

Comment: era o firewall que tava bloqueando o arquivo